PDAnnotationLink with image
Code snippet to add PDAnnotationLink
final PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();

PDBorderStyleDictionary pdBorderStyle = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
pdBorderStyle.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_BEVELED);
pdBorderStyle.setWidth(0);
txtLink.setBorderStyle(pdBorderStyle);

final PDActionURI actionURI = new PDActionURI();
actionURI.setURI ("https://stackoverflow.com/");
txtLink.setAction(actionURI);

PDRectangle pdRectangle = new PDRectangle();
pdRectangle.setLowerLeftX(250);
pdRectangle.setLowerLeftY(550);
pdRectangle.setUpperRightX(400);
pdRectangle.setUpperRightY(600);
txtLink.setRectangle(pdRectangle);

pdPage.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);

Its working fine. But I want to set Image in PDAnnotationLink.
Can I set image in PDAnnotationLink ?

Link annotations are meant to make certain areas of a page clickable with the effect of following a link. Thus, this annotation type describes the link destination and how the current content of its clickable page area will change when clicked. Additionally a full or partial border may be applied to the area. The actual content of that area, though, is meant to be there underneath the link annotation. If you want to have some image in that link area, you should add it to the static page content or a different annotation in the same area. (An appearance stream may do instead but is volatile..)

@mkl If I add image, old signature got invalidated

"If I add image, old signature got invalidated" - ah, such details had better also be mentioned in the question itself. Nonetheless, apparently you only have to consider previously existing signatures that allow annotation changes. Thus, you can position a custom stamp annotation in the link area (holding the image) and only then the link.
